# windows username and password wrong even though they are not

Tags: google-compute-engine

Today i'm facing a very strange issue with vritual machines with windows OS.
I set the username / password , but when i try to connect to a VM it says it's wrong , even though its 100% correct.
I also tried with default values and default password that is set when creating the VM - same error.
I logged in with cloud SDK , put the code to reveal the VM password and the VM contained no user or password to show.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: what version of windows OS are you having problem, and how did you try to connect to it (RDP plugin, Windows RDP client, etc)

Comment: Both of the windows OS are having the problem 2k8 and 2k12 , still to this day i'm unable to use virtual machines.

Comment: Just posted an answer on a similar subject at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715142/google-cloud-console-cannot-login-to-new-windows-vm-instance

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, just get in, after creating multiple instances until one of them works and then delete the others, it is not the best option but I have tried everything and do not function.